# How to make a submit button stand next to a search input

Tags: html, css

I wonder if i can put a submit button inside a search input, in the right side. I tried using float: right however doesn't work.

Codepen: http://codepen.io/celicoo/pen/XbKYyY

HTML:

```
<section class="search">
  <div class="search__container">
    <div class="search__row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="search__box">
          <h2 class="search__title">Procurando por: Nome de ...</h2>
          <form class="search__form" action="#" method="get">
            <input class="search__input" type="text" placeholder="Busque um Crawler.." />
            <button class="search__submit" type="submit">Procurar</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
.search {
  color: #676a6c;
  margin-top: 25px;
  &__row {
    margin-left: -15px;
    margin-right: -15px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  &__box {
    background: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 10px;
  }
  &__form {
    margin-top: 10px;
  }
  &__input {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid #e5e6e7;
    border-radius: 1px;
    color: inherit;
    display: block;
    padding: 12px;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 14px;
    outline: none;
  }
  &__input:focus {
    border: 1px solid #E97228;
  }
  &__submit {
    background-color: #E97228;
    border-color: #E97228;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    outline: none;
  }
}
```

I was trying to use float right like i said, but isn't work, the float will only push the submit button to the right, but not inside the input.

Comment: Your input is taking full width..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input for .search__input has a width of 100% so nothing can actually go beside it.

You need to make the width less than 100% and add float:left;

Example:

`.search__input{width:50%; float:left;}`

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are trying to have the submit button 'inside' the input... or overlapping it.

You need to create a wrapping `div` around the input and submit with `position: relative;`, and then give the submit button a `position: absolute;` and a top and right value.

Answer (score 0):

I added display: inline & have placed your search bar inside a container.
Try this css:

```css
.search {
  color: #676a6c;
  margin-top: 25px;

  &__row {
    margin-left: -15px;
    margin-right: -15px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  &__box {
    background: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 10px;
  }
  &__form {
    margin-top: 10px;
  }
  &__input {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid #e5e6e7;
    border-radius: 1px;
    color: inherit;
    display: block;
    padding: 12px;
    width: 50%;
    font-size: 14px;
    outline: none;
    display: inline;
    margin:0px;
  }
  &__input:focus {
    border: 1px solid #E97228;
  }
  &__submit {
    background-color: #E97228;
    border-color: #E97228;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    outline: none;
    padding: 12px;
    margin:0px;
  }
  &__container {
    width: 250px;
  }
}
```